# spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7 failed to launch, java: No such file or directory

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, path, distributed-computing

Whenever I approach to java, I have some problems.
(To use tensorflowonspark, I run the code)

At windowpowershell,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_261

 ${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-master.sh
```

`starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /mnt/c/Users/MY_PATH/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-DESKTOP-5CGUHKF.out`

`failed to launch: nice -n 0 /mnt/c/Users/MY_PATH/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host DESKTOP-5CGUHKF.localdomain --port 7077 --webui-port 8080 /mnt/c/Users/MY_PATH/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: line 71: /mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_261/bin/java: No such file or directory`

```
/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_261# cd bin

/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_261/bin# cd java
```

`bash: cd: java: No such file or directory`

```
/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_261/bin# ls
```

`appletviewer.exe  javac.exe           jcmd.exe      jmap.exe        keytool.exe       rmic.exe         vcruntime140.dll extcheck.exe      javadoc.exe         jconsole.exe  jps.exe         kinit.exe         rmid.exe         wsgen.exe idlj.exe          javafxpackager.exe  jdb.exe       jrunscript.exe  klist.exe         rmiregistry.exe  wsimport.exe jabswitch.exe     javah.exe           jdeps.exe     jsadebugd.exe   ktab.exe          schemagen.exe    xjc.exe jar.exe           javap.exe           jhat.exe      jstack.exe      native2ascii.exe  serialver.exe jarsigner.exe     javapackager.exe    jinfo.exe     jstat.exe       orbd.exe          servertool.exe java-rmi.exe      javaw.exe           jjs.exe       jstatd.exe      pack200.exe       tnameserv.exe java.exe          javaws.exe          jli.dll       jvisualvm.exe   policytool.exe    unpack200.exe`

**IN JAVA, THERE ISN'T ANY "java" FILE! HOW CAN I SOLVE IT?**

Comment: Latest Spark needs Java 11, I believe, but also, `/mnt/c` is a WSL or Cygwin address, right, not "PowerShell". `sh` scripts won't run EXE files anyway

Answer (score 1):

`java.exe` does exist in your output

You've installed Java for Windows, but using Shell scripts, which will not work together.